# Ckeditor plugins not showing up on production

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ckeditor

I'm using Ckeditor from galetahub/ckeditor in github. I have been able to install Mathjax plugin on my local ckeditor. When I push it to production (ngix + unicorn + capistrano + passenger) the Mathjax plugin doesn't show up.
Here my `ckeditor.rb`

```
  ckeditor.setup do |config|
   require "ckeditor/orm/active_record"      
  config.assets_plugins = ['lineutils','dialogui','clipboard', 'widget', 'mathjax','eqneditor', 'button', 'toolbar'] #,'dialogui', 'mathjax', 'widget', 'lineutils', 'clipboard']
end
```

Here's  `ckeditor/config.js`

```
config.extraPlugins ='lineutils,dialogui,clipboard,widget,mathjax,eqneditor,button,toolbar';
```

Here's `ckeditor.rake`

```
require 'fileutils'
desc "Create nondigest versions of all ckeditor digest assets"
task ckeditor: :environment do
  fingerprint = /\-[0-9a-f]{32}\./
  for file in Dir["public/assets/ckeditor/**/*"]
    next unless file =~ fingerprint
    nondigest = file.sub fingerprint, '.'
    FileUtils.cp file, nondigest, verbose: true
  end
end
```

Here's the production logs where `ckeditor` appears

```
"GET /assets/ckeditor/config.js?t=FB9E HTTP/1.1" 200 2740 "http://darasa.co.ke/exams/new" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0"
41.212.36.70 - - [14/Jan/2016:09:51:35 -0500] "GET /assets/ckeditor/skins/moono/editor_gecko.css?t=FB9E HTTP/1.1" 200 40695 "http://darasa.co.ke/exams/new" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0"
41.212.36.70 - - [14/Jan/2016:09:51:35 -0500] "GET /assets/ckeditor/lang/en.js?t=FB9E HTTP/1.1" 200 15729 "http://darasa.co.ke/exams/new" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0"
41.212.36.70 - - [14/Jan/2016:09:51:35 -0500] "GET /assets/ckeditor/styles.js?t=FB9E HTTP/1.1" 200 1483 "http://darasa.co.ke/exams/new" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0"
41.212.36.70 - - [14/Jan/2016:09:51:36 -0500] "GET /assets/ckeditor/skins/moono/icons.png HTTP/1.1" 200 20833 "http://darasa.co.ke/assets/ckeditor/skins/moono/editor_gecko.css?t=FB9E" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0"
41.212.36.70 - - [14/Jan/2016:09:51:36 -0500] "GET /assets/ckeditor/contents.css?t=FB9E HTTP/1.1" 200 1180 "http://darasa.co.ke/exams/new" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0"
41.212.36.70 - - [14/Jan/2016:09:51:36 -0500] "GET /assets/ckeditor/contents.css?t=FB9E HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://darasa.co.ke/exams/new" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0"
```

And the devlopment logs

```
Started GET "/assets/ckeditor/plugins/toolbar/lang/ar.self-ea252ea309c6af7b90fff0af99375b83040ee8223692cdf73a9ca05c6d00e0c9.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-14 19:03:05 +0300


Started GET "/assets/ckeditor/plugins/toolbar/lang/bg.self-41397f28721693df8f07957fee3fca4bba177a2544d0079b327572d3416d83b1.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-14 19:03:05 +0300


Started GET "/assets/ckeditor/plugins/toolbar/lang/bn.self-c0e46e758471003e889e0635137d775d879ba329393a91e4c62fd7480d53aba5.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-14 19:03:05 +0300


Started GET "/assets/ckeditor/plugins/toolbar/lang/bs.self-722ddfff65cc7e1ea17d952c88c87761b6c1daccc3fcddab453a3f71cbff8446.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-14 19:03:05 +0300


Started GET "/assets/ckeditor/plugins/toolbar/lang/ca.self-8951519ee171e4e6e74b542ec98cdb408f0b9dc7a7465211be453f0d9b2504ee.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-14 19:03:05 +0300


Started GET "/assets/ckeditor/plugins/toolbar/lang/cs.self-f3ff8f881584134f3d5fb89177819aa6a7e8b73f65cca079285569f7fdee436e.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-14 19:03:05 +0300


Started GET "/assets/ckeditor/plugins/toolbar/lang/cy.self-5fad92aa116013a2ff7b0ed84d6a5f327f14fbc29bcc359aead8c815e26e0589.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-14 19:03:05 +0300


Started GET "/assets/ckeditor/plugins/toolbar/lang/da.self-48d4a1b4290ab4d92cced0a7793a418ef82ebc76c35870c2899e99052f443adf.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-14 19:03:05 +0300
```

Seems like on development ckeditor checks the plugins folder while on production it doesn't. But that's my opinion. 
Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: check your dev tools network to see where it is being requested from and check errors in dev tools console

Comment: Just checked in my dev tools on chrome. I checked my sources, the plugins folder is not loaded at all!